# joint PDF of two stochastic processes. Is factorability linked to independence?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-analysis, independence

I am processing the timeseries of two stochastic processes $X$ and $Y$. Based on other considerations, let us assume that they are stationary.

I estimate the joint probability density function $P_{X,Y}(x,y)$ of the two processes with a histogram, and observe that it is to a good approximation factorable, i.e. I can write

$P_{X,Y}(x,y)\approx P_X(x)\,P_Y(y)$

where $P_X$ is the marginal probability density function of the process $X$.

Now, if $\{X,Y\}$ were random variables, I could conclude that the two variables are independent ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749635/does-a-factorable-joint-cdf-pdf-always-imply-independence)). I am dealing instead with two stochastic processes.

I have two questions:

- Can I say something about the independence of the two stochastic processes $X,Y$ if their joint PDF is factorable? If not, can I introduce a weaker definition of independence that they respect?
- are there other time-series processing techniques to test for the independence of the two timeseries?

Comment: 1) What is pdf (or joint pdf) for *stochastic processes*? Do you mean marginal distributions? 2) [**This**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439915/how-much-difference-is-there-between-the-independence-of-two-processes-x-t/2440425#2440425) may be an answer to your question.

Comment: @zhoraster, I think that this is essentially the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614944/independence-of-stochastic-processes