# Independence of stochastic processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, independence

Suppose that $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$ are stochastic processes defined on the same probability space whose sample paths belong to some Hilbert space $K$ (or more generally, to some function space). We may view these processes as $K$-valued random variables, hence we may talk about their independence as random variables.

> Is the [independence of stochastic processes](http://planetmath.org/IndependentStochasticProcesses) $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$ equivalent to the independence of the corresponding $K$-valued random variables?

Apologies if this is trivial, but I am lost with indices.

Comment: Why the downvote? Isn't it a legitmate question?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440334/joint-pdf-of-two-stochastic-processes-is-factorability-linked-to-independence)

Comment: @flebool, I've already linked your question to mine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understood this question correctly. The way I understood it, as we need a measure for independence, we first must think about the natural measure on $\Omega\times I$, where I is the index set of the processes corresponding to the domain of the function space. In my opinion, this would lead again to the finite dimensional distributions and thus to equivalence.